# Clichéd Chinese Pentascale?

Tags: scales

Oftentimes when a movie is expressing Asian culture, the first five notes of a pentatonic scale (usually in CM) plays in the background, sometimes preceded by a gong. I am wondering why this is and as to where/when/how the scale made its first appearance as an 'Asian' thing?

Comment: Can you link to some examples? To me, the clichéd whole tone association is with dream sequences, rather than Asia.

Comment: Ha! It wasn't the entire whole-tone scale I was talking about, more like a penta-whole-tone-scale. I'll change it.

Comment: From Wikipedia: "Most Chinese music uses a pentatonic scale, with the intervals (in terms of lǜ) almost the same as those of the major pentatonic scale". Googling "pentatonic Asian music " returns 258.000 results.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take that part out and clarify my question a bit more :)

Comment: Exoticism and so-called Orientalism were very popular in 19th (and even 18th) century classical music, although composers often didn't really portray Asian and Arabic music with any kind of accuracy, as long as it sounded exotic. Have a listen to Rameau's "Les Indes Galantes" from 1735, you may find the pentatonic scale already used there.

Comment: Some links would till be good. I've tried playing the first five notes of a whole-tone scale up and down the guitar and it really doesn't remind me of anything I'd commonly associate with Chinese culture (even in a 'film cliché" way). There is a different pentatonic scale which genuinely *is* one of the main features of Chinese music: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_musicology#Scale_and_tonality. Of course Chinese music isn't the only Asian music, and I've definitely noticed lazy directors using music from one Asian country with scenes from another!

Comment: Perhaps OP saw the whole steps between (from the pentatonic major scale) C, D, and E, and the whole steps between G and A, and mistakenly labelled it a whole-tone scale?

Comment: If it is this, then it is not known where the riff came from. [Oriental riff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oriental_riff) Included are links with more information.